# Catching start number and final number

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

i'm trying to create a regex to catch the first number in the line and the last one, but i'm having some problem with the last one:

The lines look like this:

```
00005    SALARIO MENSAL                                                 17030         36.397.291,92                                                              36.397.291,92
00010    HORAS TRABALHADAS                                              0798              19.731,93                                                                  19.731,93
```

And this is my regex:

```
(^\d+).*(\d)
```

As you can see here: http://regexr.com/3crbt is not working as expected. I can get the first one, but the last is just the last number.

Thanks!

Comment: `(\d)` just matches one digit. `(\d+)` will match one or more digits.

Comment: missing the quantifier for the last number

Comment: This isn't a job for regex. Use the split method, your fields are probably separated by tabs (or in the worst case by several spaces).

Comment: What are the expected matches? I think you could try `/^(\d+).*?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)$/`

Comment: in this example: 00005 36.397.291,92 and 00010 19.731,93 @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I need regex in this case Camisimir.

Comment: Why do you need regex, is it an assignment?

Comment: Because i'm working with a tool that allow me to create regex in order to catch data, so i don't have any choice here unless regexp hehehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(\d+).*?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY7aY2/2)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of the line
- `(\d+)` - captures into Group 1 one or more digits
- `.*?` - matches any characters but a newline, as few as possible up to
- `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)` - one or more digits followed with zero or more sequences of `,` or `.` followed with one or more digits (Group 2)
- `$` -  end of the string

The `/g` modifier ensures we get all matches and `/m` modifier makes the `^` and `$` match start and end of a *line* respectively.

Comment: Perfect! If i'm not asking to much, i'm still trying to learn RegExp with some tutoriais and sites, but for me is very confuse yet. Could you explain the second part?

Comment: Note that this might not be the best approach for huge amount of data. Getting data line by line and splitting with a tab or spaces could be the best approach (what Casimir suggested in his comment).

Comment: In my case i have a huge amount of data. Do you think is danger use regex for that? Or because of performance??

Comment: Yes, I mean performance. Still, it would not be a problem using my regex with each line. If you prefer to split with a newline first (or read the data as a stream).

Comment: Get it. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Just another tip: do not ever mention you *have to use* a regex, people become suspicious and downvote questions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following one:

(^(\d+))|(\d+$)

And its seems to work on the regexr.com thingy. But matching them up might require some assumptions that each line has at least two numbers.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make the `.*` non-greedy by changing it to `.*?` and add `+` to the second digit sequence match.

```
^(\d+).*?(\d+)$
```

If you want to match the full last number, use this:

```
^(\d+).*?([\d\.,]+)$
```

[Example](http://regexr.com/3crcf)

Comment: His second digits has commas and periods.

Comment: Updated to include this.

Comment: I just want to note that `[\d]` = `\d` and the `[\d\.,]+` (that is equal to `[\d.,]+`) can also match `,,,,,,` or `.....` at the end of a line (it might actually match a non-numeric entity).